# Sinatra app bombards server with requests

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I'm trying to write a small sinatra application following along the lines of the [screencast.org](http://screencasts.org/episodes/ajax-website-with-sinatra-jquery) screencast. I want to use jQuery for ajax along with sinatra.

As soon as I start, my app floods the server with requests. Firebug shows that the requests mount upto 2MB/second.

These are the contents of my `layout.erb`.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Is it My Birthday</title>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function getUpdate()
{
  setTimeout(getUpdate, 1000);
  $("body").load("/");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<%= yield %>


<script>
$(getUpdate);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of running once each second, it runs infinitely. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I have deployed it to heroku, please find it here http://floating-shore-4207.herokuapp.com and help me fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want it load every 1 second.

The following works, either in `<head>` or at the end of `<body>`, doesn't really matter.

```
<script>
function reload() {
  $("body").load("/");
}
setTimeout(reload, 1000);
</script>
```

The analysis done by [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12287966/231788) is correct, but the resolution is wrong... consider this function:

```
function reload() {
  setTimeout(reload, 1000);
  $("body").load("/");
}
```

When this runs, the `setTimeout` call sets the function to be called **again** one second later, but it returns immediately so the reload happens instantly. By placing `setTimeout` out of the function, we ensure the reload happens only after a second. Because the page reloads, the code is executed again, and it works!

Comment: Good catch. I'm rusty on my JavaScript `setTimeout` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout()` takes the number of milliseconds to wait before timing out and calling `getUpdate()`, so it's waiting one second then sending another `load` request. On top of that, you're loading the page, then, as the page is loading, telling it to load again, and doing that repeatedly.

Try moving your `$(getUpdate);` to the bottom of your HTML in a `<script>` tag, or inside a page event handler that fires when the page has finished loading.

---

EDIT:

> I want it load every 1 second.

Unfortunately, that isn't what you are telling it to do:

```
$(getUpdate);
function getUpdate()
{
  $("body").load("/");
```

This snippet tells the browser to immediately run `getUpdate` when it encounters `$(getUpdate);` as its parsing the JavaScript, so it does. The first thing that it's told to do then is `$("body").load("/");` which reloads the page, causing the browser to re-interpret the JavaScript, where it sees `$(getUpdate);` and immediate reloads.

Your `setTimeout(getUpdate, 1000);` never gets executed.

Change the order:

```
<script>
function getUpdate()
{
  setTimeout(getUpdate, 1000);
  $("body").load("/");
}
</script>

...
bunches of HTML
...

<script>
  $(getUpdate);
</script>
```

Comment: I want it load every 1 second.

Comment: I have moved it to the end also, but the result is the same.

Comment: @nikhil Did you change the order of the statements `setTimeout` and `$("body").load` as mentioned above?

Comment: $() runs at or after document.ready, which is right after the end of markup, so this doesn't change much.